# pyplot equivalent for pl.cm.Spectral in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have been using the code from pylab, and it works fine:

```
import pylab as pl
colors = pl.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
```

However, I want to get away from pylab because in the document it said "The pyplot interface is generally preferred for non-interactive plotting". So I tried to use `matplotlib.cm` but cannot find the equivalent. Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most common way to use matplotlib from within a script is to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

From there, you can access the `Spectral` colormap using
`plt.cm.Spectral` or through the convenience function `plt.get_cmap`. For example,

```
colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
```

or

```
colors = plt.get_cmap('Spectral')(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
```

are equivalent to

```
colors = pl.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

Should just be `cm.Spectral`

```
In [123]:

import matplotlib.cm as cm
cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0,1,10))
Out[123]:
array([[ 0.61960787,  0.00392157,  0.25882354,  1.        ],
       [ 0.84721262,  0.26120723,  0.30519032,  1.        ],
       [ 0.96378316,  0.47743176,  0.28581316,  1.        ],
       [ 0.99346405,  0.74771243,  0.43529413,  1.        ],
       [ 0.99777009,  0.93087275,  0.63306423,  1.        ],
       [ 0.94425221,  0.97770089,  0.66205308,  1.        ],
       [ 0.74771243,  0.89803922,  0.627451  ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.45305653,  0.78154557,  0.64628991,  1.        ],
       [ 0.21607075,  0.55563248,  0.73194927,  1.        ],
       [ 0.36862746,  0.30980393,  0.63529414,  1.        ]])
In [119]:

import pylab as pl
pl.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
Out[119]:
array([[ 0.61960787,  0.00392157,  0.25882354,  1.        ],
       [ 0.84721262,  0.26120723,  0.30519032,  1.        ],
       [ 0.96378316,  0.47743176,  0.28581316,  1.        ],
       [ 0.99346405,  0.74771243,  0.43529413,  1.        ],
       [ 0.99777009,  0.93087275,  0.63306423,  1.        ],
       [ 0.94425221,  0.97770089,  0.66205308,  1.        ],
       [ 0.74771243,  0.89803922,  0.627451  ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.45305653,  0.78154557,  0.64628991,  1.        ],
       [ 0.21607075,  0.55563248,  0.73194927,  1.        ],
       [ 0.36862746,  0.30980393,  0.63529414,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: Does cm.Spectral still exist?  PyDev tells me it doesn't.

Comment: Yes it actually does https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/72fa9c854e367cdebb940d311c02775a7e773244/lib/matplotlib/_cm.py#L1373.

Comment: Well, I later figured out that I can access it like `cs = cm.get_cmap('Spectral')(1.*m/K)` without pydev complaining, so that is what works for my setup for whatever reason?

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = plt.get_cmap('Spectral')(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
```

is the only working solution now.

matplotlib remove option to use:

```
colors = plt.cm.Spectral(np.linspace(0, 1, 10))
```

in the newest version.